# HTML textarea tag help required

Tags: html, css, xml, xhtml, textarea

I have set a default value in textarea. I want that when someone clicks on the textarea the default value disappears. Whats the HTML code for that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<textarea onfocus="this.value = ''">This is my default value</textarea>
```

this is the little piece of code responsible:

```
onfocus="this.value = ''"
```

basically when the focus event is fired, the value of the current field is set to an empty string `""`

of course you can make it more complexe and make sure it only erase when the element contains the default message:

```
<textarea id="myfield">This is my default value</textarea>
```

javascript:

```
var defaultMsg = "This is my default value";
document.getElementById("myfield").onfocus = function () {
   if (this.value == defaultMsg) {
      this.value = "";
   }
}

document.getElementById("myfield").onblur = function () {
   if (this.value == "") {
      this.value = defaultMsg;
   }
}
```

Comment: This will clear the value even after the user enters in his/her own text.

Comment: ok... and after that if user does not write anything and clicks out of text area, how to return default value back?

Comment: @user855360 yes the default message comes back if its empty

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the HTML5 [`placeholder`](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html) attribute:

```
<textarea name="mytext" cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="Default"></textarea>
```

This will work on all newer browsers save for IE. To cover older browser, [you can use a shim](http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/placeholder)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in HTML. You'll have to use Javascript for that. So something like this...

```
<textarea name="mytext" cols="30" rows="5" onfocus="if(this.value=='Default')this.value='';">
    Default
</textarea>
```

The `onfocus` property will allow the Javascript to execute once the textbox has focus. The Javascript checks to see if the text is the default and if it is, it will clear the textbox.

Comment: To note on tskuzzy's solution, make sure that whatever you put as the default text of your text area, that you also make that the same (case and everything) text for the `this.value=='Default'`

Answer (score 1):

try this jQuery

```
$("#id_of_textarea").focus(function(){
    $(this).val("");
    });
```

or javascript inside the textarea tag:

```
onfocus="this.value='';"
```

or for newer browsers the html5 (also in the textarea tag):

```
placeholder="Your Default String"
```

or to bring it back:

```
onfocus="if(this.value=='Default String') this.value='';"
       onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Default String';"
```

Comment: placeholder replaces the string if the user doesn't fill in the textarea and brings the focus to another element on the page.